# Where should i place the java class file so that it can be used in jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to use a java class in JSP. I placed the java class file in `WEB-INF/classes/hello.class.`

In `index.jsp` i'm creating the object for `hello` class.

I'm getting this error `"hello cannot be resolved to a type"`. Here is my jsp code,

```
<%@ page import="hello" %>
<%
    hello h = new hello();
    out.print(h.getValue());
%>
```

Comment: Check your directory structure (i.e) whether you have your class in src package and also see to ur naming conventions . java classes Start with upper case

Comment: Must see [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can add packages to get java class
in side source packages create a package 
then u can import that class in jsp page

eg-

```
<%@page import="Ab.*"%>
```

ie source packages/Ab/hello.java

Answer (score 0):

What does your class hello look like ?
(BTW, you should uppercase it : Hello)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Java class would be create under package. So while importing in jsp, use the complete path.

```
<%@ page import="com.abc.Hello" %>
```